# Calabash save login credentials

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I have a Android device connected to my PC.
Running a calabash test I use the following command:

```
calabash-android run <NAME>.apk features/<NAME>.feature
```

Every time I run this again I also have to re-login to my applications because the credentials are not stored.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely that the credentials aren't being stored as they are wiped when the app is reinstalled.  Once you have reinstall switched off for these tests it should be fine.

Comment: True! Without wipe it is stored.

Answer (score 2):

Whever you run

```
calabash-android run <NAME>.apk features/<NAME>.feature
```

Your previous app will be uninstalled & new app will be installed.

However, you can try to handle this scenario by using

Take a look at

```
features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb
```

You can remove the entire

```
"Before scenario" hook
```

since all it takes care of is reinstallation of the app under test and the test app. You can remove that code and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to reinstall your app every time you execute the testing if you change your **app_life_cycle_hooks.rb** in this way:

```
Before do |scenario|
  scenario_tags = scenario.source_tag_names

  if scenario_tags.include?('@first')

    if scenario_tags.include?('@reinstall')
      uninstall_apps
      install_app(ENV['TEST_APP_PATH'])
      install_app(ENV['APP_PATH'])
    end

    start_test_server_in_background

  end

end
```

Now, you can use tags in your scenarios to decide when to start_test_server_in_background and when to reinstall the app. For example you can do this:

```
@first @reinstall @test1
  Scenario: Run application reinstalling the app
    Given lorem ipsum
    When lorem ipsum
    Then lorem ipsum

  @first @test2
  Scenario: Run application WITHOUT reinstalling the app
    Given lorem ipsum
    When lorem ipsum
    Then lorem ipsum

  @test1 @test2
  Scenario: Other scenario without relaunching app
    Given lorem ipsum
    When lorem ipsum
    Then lorem ipsum
```

If you launch the test with @test1 tag, calabash will execute scenarios 1 and 3, and the app will be reinstalled. And if you launch with @test2 tag, the scenarios 2 and 3 will be launched without reinstall the app.